# Can serverfault.stackexchange.com be added?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

It seems like all the newer SE sites are named *topic*.stackexchange.com.

Just to keep everything orthogonal what about adding serverfault.stackexchange.com as well and point it to serverfault.com?

Comment: Apart from some abstract sense of order, are there any concrete advantages to this? (SEO, perhaps)

Comment: @Shog9 I don't believe there are any SEO advantages.

Comment: This is taking pedantry to breaking point. There has to be a *reason* to do such a thing and I seriously doubt anyone here can think of one.

Comment: So you are saying `because I want it` isn't a reason?  It may not be a good reason, but it is a reason.

Comment: "I want" is a valid reason only to a toddler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would seem logical, except none of the trilogy (SO/SF/SU) are accessible this way -- I believe the trilogy sites are still "special", and there might be a bit more involved than just the name...

If it is possible without requiring the sacrifice of a developer during the full moon I heartily approve though.

Comment: Arqade.com and askubuntu.com are special too (for possibly different reasons). For SE2 sites, getting your own domain name is a badge of honour.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't see much of a problem coming from redirecting serverfault.stackexchange.com -> serverfault.com. But I'm sure the codebase uses the hostname of the site, so I doubt it would be trivial to add alternate hostnames to sites.

Arqade (gaming.stackexchange.com) already does this in the reverse, arqade.com -> gaming.stackexchange.com

Comment: That's true, if it's implemented as a 3xx redirect I don't expect it would be any issue since the browser is just going to re-request the page with the redirect target URI.